# how can i post the value of appointmentid?

Tags: php, post

if (isset($_POST['update'])){
        $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE appointment SET appointmentstatusid='$_POST[appointmentstatusid]' WHERE appointmentstatusid='$_POST[appointmentstatusid]'";
        mysql_query($UpdateQuery);
        };

```
$query2 = "SELECT * from appointmentstatus"; 
$result = mysql_query($query2);
echo "<select name=appointmentstatusid>"; 
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=".$line['appointmentstatusid'].">"; 
    echo $line['appointmentstatus'];
    echo "</option>";
}
echo $_POST["appointmentstatusid"];
echo "</select>";
```

I would like to post `appointmentstatusid`, but when running it, I receive an `undefined index appointmentstatusid` error (referencing the one inside `$_POST[]`), but I am not sure why. not sure if there's something wrong with my where clause in my update.

Comment: Have you submitted the form when you run this script? If not, there won't be anything in `$_POST`.

Comment: Have you actually sent any post-data with the name `appointmentstatusid`? I don't quite see why you would want to `echo` that

Comment: There shouldn't be anything between `<select>` and `</select>` other than `<option>` and `<optgroup>`. Why are you echoing that there? Do you want to make the old value selected by default?

Comment: yes, i have submitted the form when i run the script

Comment: between <select> and </select> im getting values in drop down menu and i would like to post the one that is picked.

Comment: Is your form using the post method? as your code works OK for me.

Comment: @Malcolm yes. as i submit it should update appointmentstatusid but its not working and says undefined index appointmentstatusid.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you well, you need to pass the value of $line['appointmentstatus'] to another page with a form POST. Is this right?

If yes you need to do

```
     <form action="http://target.url" name="" id="" method="POST">
<input type='hidden' name='appointment_status' value='$line['appointmentstatus']'>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.document.forms[0].submit();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `echo $_POST["appointmentstatusid"];` in that code you put in your question and THEN submit the form. On the page where you post the form you should have a value in the `$_POST["appointmentstatusid"]` variable.